# How to Measure periodic events using Prometheus counter metrics?

Tags: c#, prometheus, grafana, promql

We have .net core background service, which is listening to queue, every one hour once queue will receive same kind of messages from our another application, our background service which is listening to the queue will pick it and process it, there are multiple instances (kubernetes pods) of our background service is running, all listening to the same queue, I want to capture how many message processed successfully, or failed given in every hour.

I want to know any big deviation happens with processed messages in the hour interval. I am planning to use counter metrics to capture the events, is that the right choice?

11 - 12: 20 Message processed successfully
12 - 13: 20 Message processed successfully
13 - 14 : 1 Message processed successfully
14 - 15 : 20 Message processed successfully

I want to set alert when there is deviation like in the interval 13 - 14 time frame happens, I also want to see this as grafana graph. I also want to see the same kind of graph at day level. I don't want total processed count at day level, I want average of events happened every hour at that particular day.

Is `sum_over_time(mycount[1hr])` function will give what I expect, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your app started at 10:00, and processed number of messages each hour according to your example (and all messages were processed within one scrape tick at 00 minutes for ease of example). Then value of your counter should be:

- 10:00 - 11:00 - `0`
- 11:00 - 12:00 - `20`
- 12:00 - 13:00 - `40`
- 13:00 - 14:00 - `41`
- 14:00 - 15:00 - `61`

To extract your datapoints back you can use `increase(mycount[1h])`: this will return increase of your counter over last hour (t-1h, t), where t is current time - not something like `11:00-12:00`. But latter can be accomplished with step specified to `1h` if needed.

Also, please notice, that range selector is `1h`, not `1hr`.

`sum_over_time(mycount[1h])` will give you completely unrelated data - don't use it.

Comment: I want to know how much event processed at each hour, I am not worried about how much it increased from previous hour, when I used increase function, it gives me floating data points, however I am interested in  knowing how many events happened every hour? If counter is not correct metrics for such scenarios also point me in correct direction.

Comment: @Mohanraja, please read what counter is and how it works. Increase is the correct approach. Increase [can produce non integer results](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase). You can mitigate this with `round` if needed. Or with using manual difference calculation using `offset`.